# How do i instantiate or set a layout for android in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a new layout in my res/layout folder and the problem i have is that i dont know how to make the layout run in my emulator.My emulator runs the layout that comes when a new android project is made.iHave tried changing it in the setContent view in the .java file that comes with the project but that gives me errors

Comment: pls give your code for changing view (java code) and your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a layout defined in res/layout/foo.xml you would set/use it in your Activity as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.foo);
    ...
}
```

I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setContentView();` is used to achieve what you want to. This is generally done by placing the method in your `onCreate()` as follows:

`setContentView(R.layout.foo);` where `R` is the resource, `layout` is the folder and `foo` is the name of your XML layout file that you want to display.

The same can also be achieved dynamically by first declaring your layout and setting that instance in the `setContentView();` method as shown below:

`setContentView(ll);` where `ll` could be your layout's instance.

Hopefully, this solves your issue.